# GE fridge/freezer stops cooling

Tags: electrical

My old GE side by side refrigerator/freezer stops cooling and I hit the thermostat and it comes back on and will run good for a while and does it again and I have to hit it again to get it to come back on I replaced the thermostat and still does the same thing going to try another thermostat to see if that’s the problem any suggestions?

Comment: Did you replace the thermostat with a new thermostat? Is the fan/blower running and just not blowing cold air? Model number or photos may help.

Comment: Compressor motor overheating ?

Comment: Having to smack it for it to work sounds like a loose connection somewhere or a valve sticking.  Might not be the thermostat at all, but something close by.